# Why is the setTimeout function used here?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The following code is from [Essential JavaScript Design Patterns For Beginners](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript). Why is the  setTimeout function used here?

```
var pubsub = {};
(function(q) {

    var topics = {},
        subUid = -1;

    q.publish = function(topic, args) {

        if (!topics[topic]) {
            return false;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
            var subscribers = topics[topic],
                len = subscribers ? subscribers.length : 0;

            while (len--) {
                subscribers[len].func(topic, args);
            }
        }, 0);

        return true;

    };

    q.subscribe = function(topic, func) {

        if (!topics[topic]) {
            topics[topic] = [];
        }

        var token = (++subUid).toString();
        topics[topic].push({
            token: token,
            func: func
        });
        return token;
    };

    q.unsubscribe = function(token) {
        for (var m in topics) {
            if (topics[m]) {
                for (var i = 0, j = topics[m].length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (topics[m][i].token === token) {
                        topics[m].splice(i, 1);
                        return token;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
}(pubsub));
```

Comment: Relevant question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113840/using-settimeout-to-improve-responsiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way the `publish` function returns immediately, in some way scheduling given code block to be executed immediately later (asynchronously).

Looks like it notifies a bunch of listeners, so the author wanted to run the notification loop later, not blocking the `publish` code. Also note that the result of notification (if any) is not needed for the client code.

A side effect is that if one of the subscribers throw an exception, the `publish` method is not affected (different call stack).

Maybe it is not idiomatic, but it is quite common pattern in JavaScript. Sometimes it is also used to let other events/timeout to run - especially in very long-running function.

Comment: Thanks. So will the function supplied to setTimeout run on a different thread?

Comment: @Ben: no threads in ECMAscript (forgetting about webworkers). It just means, that this job is added to the "UI queue" later. Javascript code runs in the same thread the browser updates the UI, all jobs are queued in a big message loop. Its the principle of cooperative multitasking.

Comment: Well, there are no threas *per se* in JavaScript. Rather think about a queue of events running one after another in single worker thread. When `publish` returns, it releases the worker threads, which is immediately used to handle another event. It might be the `setTimeout` with 0. It may also be some other event that was waiting longer. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266918).

Comment: Seeing as ECMAscript is single threaded does this merely permit the UI thread to take a breath before the publish function does its work? If so, might I instead expect to *also* see the setTimeout being used within the while(len--) loop to mitigate the potentially long running notification process?

Comment: @Ben: I have never seen such pattern. Note that JavaScript is mostly asynchronous (e.g. AJAX), long-running blocking functions aren't that often.

Comment: @Tomasz thanks for your help. You say asynchronous, but given that JS runs on the browser UI thread, if I invoke a method that counts to a hundred million, that will surely block the UI (i.e. invocation is synchronous)?

Comment: @Ben: Yes. you can even call AJAX synchronously, which might freeze the entire UI for seconds...