# How to get a callback from a 'one' event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a javascript application and there is sometimes a need to do a trigger-click. Calling the trigger, the app wait once for an animation end and run a few lines codes after that. But the script doesn't wait until the animation end and continues with other code.

The problem is hard to describe, so here's my code:

```
var $output = $('#output');

$('#link-1').click(function(){
    $('#link-2').trigger('click');
    $output.append('<div>Second output</div>');
});

$('#link-2').click(function(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    $obj.toggleClass('active');

    $obj.one('transitionend', function(){
        $output.append('<div>First output</div>');
    });
});
```

The result looks like:

```
<div id="output">
    <div>Second output</div>
    <div>First output</div>
</div>
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/MKZvZ/1/

How can i achieve that `First output` appears before `Second output`?

`First output` and `Second output` are just basic examples, in effect the app doe's some logic work.

Comment: Try to describe your problem here, without asking people to visit a link.

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function to delay a process

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
        // this will execute 1 second later
    }, 1000);
```

Please refer the below link. Here they can explain how to delay the execution. You can delay your execution until your animation get over.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912655/javascript-how-to-put-a-simple-delay-in-between-execution-of-javascript-code](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

Not an elegant solution, but nevertheless

http://jsfiddle.net/MKZvZ/2/

```
var $output = $('#output');

$('#link-1').click(function(){    
    var func = function(){
        $output.append('<div>Second output</div>');
    }
    $('#link-2').trigger('click',func);
});

$('#link-2').click(function(event,func){
    var $obj = $(this);
    $obj.toggleClass('active');

    $obj.one('transitionend', function(){
        $output.append('<div>First output</div>');
        func.call();
    });

});
```